# How do I separate data from one column into two

Tags: r, string

I have a column `data$Floor`  from a dataset imported from CSV that supposedly contains the floor of an apartment. Here is a sample data:

| Floor |
| --- |
| Ground out of 2 |
| 1 out of 3 |

I wish to separate the data to have the floor and the total floors as following:

| Floor | Total Floors |
| --- | --- |
| Ground | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

I have done `write(str_replace_all(data$Floor, "out of", " "), data)` with the intention of splitting the columns where the space is, then writing the changes to the dataset `data` but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate`:

```r
tidyr::separate(data, Floor, c('Floor', 'Total Floors'), sep = ' out of ')
#>    Floor Total Floors
#> 1 Ground            2
#> 2      1            3
```

---

**Data used**

```r
data <- data.frame(Floor = c("Ground out of 2", "1 out of 3"))

data
#>             Floor
#> 1 Ground out of 2
#> 2      1 out of 3
```

Comment: hey, thanks for helping me

solution throws an error : 
"Error in UseMethod("separate") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "function""

Comment: @newb-itstudent that's probably because I used a data frame called `df`. Obviously, you need to put whatever your data frame is called in place of `df`. I have updated to change the data frame name to `data`, as in your example - try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` from base R.

```
strsplit(data$Floor, ' out of ') |> rbind.data.frame() |> setNames(c('Floor', 'Total Floors'))
#    Floor Total Floors
# 1 Ground            1
# 2      2            3
```